# Cant Create folder with full permission on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, permissions, php, mkdir

I having a weird problem on my VPS with Ubuntu 14.04 as the server. I tried creating a directory with php mkdir using the code below

```
<?php 
    mkdir("/items/foldername", 0777, true);
?>
```

Whenever i run this script,the folder gets created but with 755 permission instead of 777.

I have tried all available options I can see none is working. My php script is using www-data.

I have tried the following

1. `sudo chmod -R 777 items`
2. `sudo chmod -R g+s items`
3. I added `www-data` to the root group

Comment: What are these "all available options" that you have tried?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16672429/how-to-set-default-permissions-for-new-files-created-with-php

Comment: @ Rinzwind, that was just an example, the folder is being created where I want it to, its just that the folders are not being created with the right permission.

Comment: @ muru, I get permission denied when I tried your example

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16672717/2072269 gave a permission error?

Comment: I mean I want to do this with my php code not on my terminal

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16672717/2072269 looks like PHP code to me.

Comment: @muru, I tried your suggested answer, it doesnt work for me

Comment: @muru, I think you should post your suggestion as an answer, the umask solution you suggestes just work for me now, Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16672717/2072269):

> You can use `umask()` immediately before the fopen() call, but umask
>   shouldn't be used if you're on a multi-threaded server - it'll change
>   the mask for ALL threads (e.g. this change is at the process level),
>   not just the one that you're about to use fopen() in.
>
> e.g.
>
> ```
> $old = umask(000);
> fopen('foo.txt', 'w'); // creates a 0666 file
> umask($old) // restore original mask
> ```
>
> It'd be easier to simply chmod() after the fact, however:
>
> ```
> fopen('foo.txt', 'w'); // create a mode 'who cares?' file
> chmod('foo.txt', 0666); // set it to 0666
> ```